# The Sonos audioclip api reduces auth param length

Tags: authorization, sonos, audioclip

The Sonos audioclip api https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/audioclip/loadaudioclip/ allows passing in the `httpAuthorization` param that is then passed along as an Authorization header.  Not sure why, but the auth param is being reduced to the first 128 chars instead of passing it all along with the streaming url request.

Answer (score 0):

As of the recently released software version 10.4, Sonos supports an `httpAuthorization` value of 512 bytes. See the [`loadAudioClip`](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/audioclip/loadaudioclip/) documentation for details. See the [Sonos version 10.4 platform features](https://developer.sonos.com/release-notes/sonos-version-10-4-platform-features/) release notes for other updates.